# The past continuous with an anchor

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

1 I played yesterday

2 I was playing yesterday

We use 1 when we refer to what we did we do not need to add anything to 1 to be correct. When it comes to 2 when it's on its own then it's grammaticlly correct but unlikely we need to add a time frame like " for two hours" or add additional thing like " I was playing yesterday when you called" this additional thing may be just stated or implied to make it natural na likely. Is that right?